# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I created a new project via composer create-project laravel/laravel Test 5.4.* then i go to my browser to see my localhost if its working localhost/test/public and it works it redirect me to the welcome page, but when i tried to test

```
Route::get('/test', function(){
  return 'TEST';
});
```

Then I go to my localhost/test/public/test it shows me error like

```
NotFoundHttpException: in RouteCollection.php (line 179)
```

Comment: You should go to `localhost/test/public` and/or `localhost/test/public/test`

Comment: @Abhishek sorry my bad thats  what i meant localhost/test/public/test but still gets an error, even if i tried someother names like create i still get the error.

Comment: the route looks correct. Are you sure your vhost configuration or .htaccess (in your /public dir) are correct?

Comment: i've change something on my vhost

Comment: @Abhishek i put something like this <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"
    ServerName lsapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
 on my first project.

Comment: @bLuke its still now working, i haven't change anything yet.

Comment: vhost looks correct. Can you share your .htaccess in your project public dir?

Comment: @bLuke here it is, <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

Comment: this looks correct too. I saw in your vhost file that you have both localhost and lsapp.dev pointing at the same project. Have you modified your hosts (in c:windows/system32/drivers/etc dir) with 127.0.0.1 lsapp.dev?

Have you tried to access your project with lsapp.dev/test?

Comment: @bLuke the first project i created was the lsapp and its still working up to now, after that i created new project but i didnt modify anything else

Comment: so you currently have 2 projects: one named "test" and the first one named "lsapp". In your vhosts conf you have localhost and lsapp that are pointing at the same directory  `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/lsapp/public"`. First, i suggest you to leave localhost pointing at `c:xampp/htdocs`. In the end I suggest you to setup a proper vhost named test.dev and make it point to the test project directory. Update your hosts in windows/system32/drivers/etc, restart apache and try again. You should visit that page via test.dev/test...

Comment: HAve you enable  mode_rewrite extension of your server?

Comment: @bLuke i've tried to undo all of what i've done in vhost and hosts, but still i got the same error.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan where can i see that?

Comment: @Josel Parayno, are you working on local? Xampp or wamp?

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan xampp

Comment: @Josel Parayno ok , let me check..then I will tell you

Comment: @Muhammad Rizwan localhost/test/public can access but when i try to use localhost/test/public/anything i always got the error i dont know why.

Comment: @Josel Parayno if you have installed xammp on C drive then go to httpd.conf at C:\xampp\apache\conf\ and make sure there must be no # before LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so in httpd.conf and then check your laravels urls again if they are working or not. Don't forget to restart xampp server after making changes in httpd.conf file

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan it doesn't have # before LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite, its still doesn't change the error.

Comment: can you printscreen your .htaccess file?

Comment: i already solved it, i just deleted what I've edited in the httpd.conf and vhost, then created a new project using composer.

Answer (score 0):

is it a solved issue? 
instead of `localhost/test/public/test` try `localhost/test/public/index.php/test`.
of course you can use laravel's own server. it is suitable for most developing  usages.